# How can I select and call a tempo template inside a tempo template?

Tags: template, skeleton

I am writing a set of [tempo](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TempoMode) templates in order to help me writing [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/) boilerplate code.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/atorres1985-junkyard/etc/blob/trunk/home-configurations/anderson/dotfiles/emacs/extra-lisp.d/001-nix-tempo.el), and I will refer to it henceforth.

The workflow I intent is similar to this:

1. Call `tempo-template-nixpkgs-mkderivation`;
2. When the template asks about the fetcher (it can be `nixpkgs-fetchurl` or `nixpkgs-fetchfromgithub`), save it;
3. At the time of insert the saved fetcher, call the corresponding `tempo-template` as in a recursive behaviour;
4. When finished the inner template insertion, continue to the outer.

Question: how can I implement this workflow?

(As an extra, I would like to do the same but with [skeletons](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode).)